How to Fullscreen Ruffle flash player embedded on Google sites
I can't figure out how to Fullscreen my embedded ruffle player on Google sites.
For background, I am trying to make a personal unblocked games website for me to play flash games at school because all of the flash games on the other unblocked games have been blocked. For more background I have some minor experience with html (very minimal) and I little more knowledgeable in JavaScript because I am currently taking a class on it.
I have tried looking through forums and Ruffle's official page but I either can' find a solution, or I do I don't understand it. I have tried little snippets of code I have found but it doesn't seem to be working. When I couldn't figure anything out I went to Classroom 6x(another unblocked games website) to see how they incorporated Full screen with ruffle. I noticed that there was no Fullscreen button embedded like the other games but this time when I opened the right click context menu their was a full screen option.(something that isn't  appearing for my flash games
So I guess my final question is how do I get the Fullscreen option to appear in the right click context menu . Unless there is any better way to do it . . .
I don't exactly sure what I'm doing so explain in simple terms what I have to do.
Also I found this , but I don't know how to incorporate it into my code.post I found
My current embedded code:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle"></script>

<embed src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axolotlstudiosyt/henry-stickmin-legacy-collection/main/fleeing_the_complex.swf" width="1080" height="720"></embed>

<body>

</html>



I googled and found out that you can invoke fullscreen mode on the Ruffle HTML element: https://ruffle.rs/js-docs/master/classes/RufflePlayer.html#enterFullscreen

It is called about:blank cloaking here is 2 little snippets

Example
the second one is but you either need Ultraviolet Super confusing to set up, and Works for iframes like Google.com 4, which has their permissions blocked for iframing, or there is about blank cloaking. I am going to stick with about:blank cloaking.
Here is the in general code:

Open Game function openGame() { var win = window.open() var url = "" //use your own link google com and other sites like minecraft.net will not work. var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe') iframe.style.width = "100%"; iframe.style.height = "100%"; iframe.style.border = "none"; iframe.src = url win.document.body.appendChild(iframe) }

Please edit the answer to the put code into blocks delimited by triple-back-ticks. That will make the iframe node visible in your answer and allow you to indent the openGame function in a normal way. The middle paragraph could also be more comprehensible if it were broken into a bulleted list that separated the two options.

Yes I am aware of ab cloaking. Thank you for this response as I may use this code else ware for future projects. I couldn't figure out myself how to get it to work however when I copy and paste my embedded code into a .html file and open it in the browser, when I right click there is a fullscreen option. I have no idea why this is and why it wasn't working on Google sites. Could you explain to me how to incorperate my embedded code into the ab cloaked tab instead of using a single link? I suppose I can compose everything  into gihub pages but it would still be nice to know.
